# How many people were actually in the Beast's castle?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast

In Disney's *Beauty and the Beast*, one of the central premises is that the various people in the castle were turned into objects by the curse (i.e., Lumiere, Mrs. Potts, Cogsworth, and so on).  Being a fairly large castle, it makes sense that there were a fair number of people.

However, after watching the movie recently, it dawned on me - were all of the objects in the castle given life? In the fight scene at the end alone, there are probably 50+ knives that attack Gaston's henchmen, not to mention all of the various other items.  I doubt there were 50+ servants who were turned into knives (not to mention various other cutlery).

Is there an official explanation for this, or perhaps a list of the people who were in the castle (and had names)?  And does that mean that all of those items that were given life by the curse had it taken away when the curse was broken? (A bit macabre to think about, IMO.)

Or am I just overthinking a beloved family movie? (That's a rhetorical question that I can answer quite easily.)

Comment: Well, in comparison, Buckingham palace has 188 staff bedrooms (Not used as much in modern day as it was before), and the Master of the Household, the head manager for all the Kitchen, Service, and housecleaning controls about 250 staff members. Not including soldiers, or children of any live-in staff, like Mrs. Pott's kid. There were also animals turned, including horses and the ottoman dog.

Comment: It would be interesting to know an official count of how many unique sentient objects appear on screen

Answer (score 6):

### 13 or 14 named people

So far I have the following named servents:

From ***Beauty and the Beast***

- Lumière
- Cogsworth
- Mrs. Potts
- Chip Potts
- Babette
- The Wardrobe
- Chef Bouche

From ***Beauty and the Beast: The Enchanted Christmas***

- Forte
- Fife
- Angelique

From ***Belle's Magical World***

- Webster
- Crane
- LePlume
- Possibly *Witherspoon* though he could just be a pigeon

For the non-named objects that dance along in "Be Our Guest" there are three ways of these could be reconciled. 
Either:

1. They are not sentient at all, merely normal non servant household object and are dancing along because this is a Disney cartoon and things like that happen.
2. They are all sentient and therefore all members of the Beasts household
3. Only those objects depicted with eyes are the sentient, transformed members of beasts household. Some of the cutlery has eyes as per this screenshot

[image: CutleryWithEyes]

There is no source I can find that gives an answer as to which of the 3 choices is correct.